# Getting Started With Ubuntu

Tags: software-center

I installed Ubuntu over a year ago on my Dell PC.  I have just decided to try to run FreeBasic on the Ubuntu system.  On powering-up my PC I have used the 'select Ubuntu' option but even after an hour has elapsed, all I get on the screen is your purple'ish-coloured background (same as background on this page), and it periodically displays a log-on/sign-in box for about 2 seconds.  I have no idea what to do next.  (Am using Internet Explorer & WindowsXP, unaware of version no. for Ubuntu)

Comment: Is the login screen you see text-based or graphical?